# Do math from document.getElementById() with AJAX

Tags: python, html, ajax

I have Python code like this

```
@app.route('/generate/transaction', methods=['POST'])
def generate_transaction():
    sender_public_key = request.form['sender_public_key']
    sender_private_key = request.form['sender_private_key']
    recipient_public_key = request.form['recipient_public_key']
    amount = request.form['amount']

    transaction = Transaction(sender_public_key, sender_private_key, recipient_public_key, amount)

    response = {'transaction': transaction.to_dict(),
                'signature': transaction.sign_transaction()}

    return jsonify(response), 200
```

and in HTML/AJAX I have this one

```
$(function() {
        $("#generate_transaction").click(function() {
            $.ajax({
                url: "/generate/transaction",
                type: "POST",
                dataType: 'json',
                data: $('#transaction_form').serialize(),
                success: function(response) {

                    document.getElementById('confirmation_sender_public_key').value = response['transaction']['sender_public_key'];
                    document.getElementById('confirmation_recipient_public_key').value = response['transaction']['recipient_public_key'];
                    document.getElementById('confirmation_amount').value = response['transaction']['amount'];

                    document.getElementById('transaction_signature').value = response['signature'];
    }
```

I want to have any input for `amount` that can turn into `amount = amount * 10%`
But I can not figure where to change it

Answer (score 1):

assuming that you want to do the equation, you could simply add another command, e.g.

```
@app.route('/generate/transaction', methods=['POST'])
def generate_transaction():
    sender_public_key = request.form['sender_public_key']
    sender_private_key = request.form['sender_private_key']
    recipient_public_key = request.form['recipient_public_key']
    amount = request.form['amount']
    fraction_amount = amount * 0.1

    transaction = Transaction(sender_public_key, sender_private_key, 
                              recipient_public_key, fraction_amount)

    response = {'transaction': transaction.to_dict(),
                'signature': transaction.sign_transaction()}

    return jsonify(response), 200
```

Let me know if that is what you meant.

Comment: Nice answer! I hope you don't mind that I cleaned up the code a bit. Welcome to SO :)